# adding friendship logic in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

so I'm building a notes app with Ruby on rails where you can crete notes and notes collections, add friends and see your friend's notes and notes collections from their profile.

I tried to implement these:
-create a page where you can see all the users in the app and a button next to them where I can click to add friend.

- create a page where I can see the friend requests and accept or deny them.
- create a page where I can see all my friends listed and when I click on one of them I can see their profile where I can see their notes and collections.

right now I can click on add friend but a friend request doesn't send.
I tried lots of different things that I don't even know what I haven't tried, yet it's such a simple problem.

how can i fix it and add this feature (basically just following)

models/friendship.rb

```
class Friendship < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :friend, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'friend_id'

  scope :pending, -> { where(status: 'pending') }

  validates :user_id, uniqueness: { scope: :friend_id }
end
```

models/friend_request.rb

```
class FriendRequest < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :sender, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :receiver, class_name: "User"

  validates :sender, presence: true
  validates :receiver, presence: true
end
```

models/users.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable


         # Add :username to the devise method
         validates :username, presence: true, uniqueness: true

         has_many :notes
         has_many :collections
         scope :private_to_user, ->(user) { where(user_id: user.id) }

         has_many :friendships
          has_many :friends, through: :friendships, source: :friend

          def friends
            friends = friendships.where(status: 'accepted').pluck(:friend_id)
            User.where(id: friends)
          end

          def pending_friendships
           Friendship.pending.where(friend: self)
         end

end
```

controllers/users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @users = User.where.not(id: current_user.id)
  end
  def friends
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @friends = @user.friends.where(friendships: { status: 'accepted' })
  end




  def add_friend
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    current_user.friendships.create(friend: @user)
    redirect_to users_path, notice: 'Friend request sent.'
  end
end
```

controllers/friendships.controller.rb

```
class FriendshipsController < ApplicationController
    def index
      @friend_requests = current_user.friendships.where(status: 'pending')
    end




  def update
    friendship = Friendship.find(params[:id])
    friendship.update(status: 'accepted')
    redirect_to friendships_path, notice: 'Friendship request accepted.'
  end

  def destroy
    friendship = Friendship.find(params[:id])
    friendship.destroy
    flash[:notice] = 'Friendship removed.'
    redirect_to friendships_path
  end
end
```

friendships/index.html.erb

```
<h1>Friendship Requests</h1>
<ul>
  <% @friend_requests.each do |friendship| %>
    <li>
      <%= friendship.user.username %>
      <%= link_to "Accept", accept_friendship_path(friendship), method: :put %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Comment: The correct place to send a friendship request mail is certainly below `current_user.friendships.create(friend: @user)`. Do you already have a mailer for the friendship request? Please share it too.

Comment: i don't think i have. what exactly is it?

Comment: When you wrote _"but a friend request doesn't send"_, what exactly do you expect to be sent? An email to the invited user?

Comment: Please keep in the question only relevant code. Looks like too much details

Comment: no inside of the app i'm just trying to send a friend request smilar as in any social media app like twitter. in the friend requests page i want to be able to see that request but it doesnt appear